# How to implement "SQL Transactions" in "Clean Architecture"?

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, clean-architecture

I am working on an Express-based (Nodejs) API that uses MySQL for data persistence. I have tried to follow the CLEAN ARCHITECTURE proposed by Sir R.C. Martin.

Long story short:-

There are some crop vendors and some users. A user can request an order of some crops with a defined quantity from a vendor. This puts the order in PENDING state. Then the vendor will confirm the orders he/she gets from the user.

Domain/Entity -> CROP, Use-case -> add, remove, edit, find, updateQty

Domain/Entity -> ORDER, Use-case -> request, confirm, cancel

I have to implement a confirm order functionality

- I have an already recorded order with ordered item list in my DB (order in the pending state)
- Now on confirming order action I need to subtract each item quantity from respective crop present in the DB record, with a check that no value turns negative (i.e. no ordered qty is more than present qty)
- If it is done for all the items under a "transaction cover" then I have to commit the transaction
- Else revert back to the previous state (i.e rollback)

I know how to run Mysql specific transactions using "Sequelize", but with a lot of coupling and poor source code architecture. (If I do it that way, then DB won't be like plugin anymore)

I am not able to understand how to do this while maintaining the architecture and at what layer to implement this transaction thing, use-case/data-access, or what?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is recommended to share the snap(not an image, but the code itself) of the code/work that you have done along with the problem. This will help to figure out what can be done better.

Comment: This almost reads like a subjective task - understanding whole use case and then project code to verify your hypothesis of "tight coupling"  and "poor code". 
Suggestion - When on SO, you should focus on asking questions  which are very  specific ones. That too after your initial research and effort on the same.

Comment: hey @Anshul Garg, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend keeping the transaction in the "adapters layer" by using "unit of work" pattern. This way the database remains a plug-in to the business logic.